# How to resolve a promise on a controller?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Hi I have a `modelA` and `modelB`

my `modelA.js` has something like this

```
  modelBs: DS.hasMany('modelB', { async: true })
```

and my `modelB.js` has something like this

```
  modelA: DS.belongsTo('modelA', { async: true })
  status: DS.attr('string'),

  statusOne: Ember.computed.filterBy('status', 'one'),
  statusTwo: Ember.computed.filterBy('status', 'two'),
```

However, I have a template that has a each loop for my `modelA` which looks something like this

```
 {{#each modelAs as |modelA|}}
   {{modelA.someAttribute}}
   {{modelA.modelBs.statusOne.length}}
 {{/each}}
```

My question is why does my `{{modelA.modelBs.statusOne.lenght}}` returned `0` value whereas this user has more than 1 `statusOne` value

Comment: How are you fetching your data?  Are you seeing the correct requests and responses in your Network tab?  And if you have the Ember Inspector installed, take a look at the data there.

Comment: and where are your `statusOne` and `statusTwo` computed properties?

Comment: Hi @donleche my statusOne and statusTwo is located on the modelBs.js model.

Comment: modelA.modelBs is an array. modelA.modelBs.@each.statusOne.length makes sense, modelA.modelBs.statusOne, does not make much sense to me.

Comment: hi @dwenzel i am not seeing any records on `reservations` when I tried to look on my ember inspector.